# Como deixo essa lista duplamente encadeada e circular?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada, referência-circular

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Tipo_Lista{
    char cod[50] ;
    struct Tipo_Lista *Prox;
    struct Tipo_Lista *Ant;
};
struct Tipo_Lista *Primeiro;
struct Tipo_Lista *Ultimo;

void FLVazia(){
    struct Tipo_Lista *aux;
    aux = (struct Tipo_Lista*)malloc(sizeof(struct Tipo_Lista));
    Primeiro = aux;
    Ultimo = Primeiro;
    Primeiro->Ant = NULL;

}
void Insere(char *x){
    struct Tipo_Lista *aux;
    aux = (struct Tipo_Lista*)malloc(sizeof(struct Tipo_Lista));
    strcpy(aux->cod,x);
    Ultimo->Prox = aux;
    aux->Ant = Ultimo;
    Ultimo = Ultimo->Prox;
    aux->Prox = NULL;
}
void Imprime(){
    struct Tipo_Lista *aux;
    aux = Primeiro->Prox;
    while(aux != NULL){
        printf("Item = %s\n",aux->cod);
        aux = aux->Prox;
    }
}
void Imprime_Atras(){
    struct Tipo_Lista *aux;
    aux = Ultimo;
    while(aux->Ant != NULL){
        printf("Item = %s\n",aux->cod);
        aux = aux->Ant;
    }
}
void Pesquisa(char *x){
    struct Tipo_Lista *aux;
    struct Tipo_Lista *aux2;

    int flag = 0;
    aux = Primeiro->Prox;
    while(aux != NULL){



        if(strcmp (aux->cod,x) == 0){
            aux2 = aux->Ant;
            aux = aux->Prox;
            printf("Achou item %s seu anterior é %s seu próximo é %s ", x,aux2->cod,aux->cod);
            flag = 1;
            aux = NULL;
        }
        else 
        aux = aux->Prox;
    }
    if(flag == 0){
        printf("Item %s Não se encontra nesta Lista!!!!",x);
    }
}

void Remove(char *x){
    int retorno;
    struct Tipo_Lista *aux;
    int flag = 0;
    aux = Primeiro->Prox;
    while(aux != NULL){
        retorno = strcmp (aux->cod,x);
        if(retorno == 0){
            if(aux->Prox == NULL){
                Ultimo = aux->Ant;
                aux->Ant->Prox = NULL;
                aux = NULL;
                flag = 1;
            }
            else{

            printf("Removeu item %s\n",x);
            aux->Ant->Prox = aux->Prox;
            aux->Prox->Ant = aux->Ant;
            aux = NULL;
            flag = 1;
        }
        }
        else
        aux = aux->Prox;
    }
    free(aux);
    if (flag == 0){
        printf("Item %s Não se encontra nesta Lista!!",x);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char op = '2';
    int i;
    char codigo[50];
    FLVazia();
    while(op != '0'){
        printf("Encontre com o codigo: ");
        gets(codigo);
        Insere(codigo);
        printf("\n\n\nContinuar com o cadastro? 1 = sim 0 = Não: \n\n");
        op = getch();
    }
    Imprime();
    printf("\n\n Entre com um item para pesquisa: ");
    gets(codigo);
    Pesquisa(codigo);
    printf("Item a ser removido: ");
    gets(codigo);
    Remove(codigo);
    Imprime();
    getch();
    Imprime_Atras();
    getch();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Poderia dar mais detalhes sobre o que você quer? Qual parte do código você gostaria de alterar ou melhorar?

Comment: esta tudo duplamente encadeado , gostaria de torna-la circular agora , de forma que quando eu chamasse a função pesquisa , passando o último elemento ela me retornasse o penúltimo como anterior e o primeiro como próximo , e se passasse o primeiro que ele me retornasse o último como anterior e o segundo como próximo.

Comment: Para uma lista ser circular o ultimo elemento deve apontar o próximo para o primeiro elemento da lista, já o primeiro elemento da lista deve apontar o seu anterior para o ultimo da lista. 

Minha sugestão é modificar o método "Insere" ele deve ter o papel de controlar a lista circular, também irá ser preciso modificar o método Remove pois ele deve ser inteligente o suficiente para casos de eliminação do ultimo elemento que ocasiona a modificação dos ponteiros de referencia.

Answer (score 1):

Seguinte o ultimo elemento tem que apontar para o cabeça de lista e o cabeça de lista para o ultimo elemento,você pode pega o ponteiro do cabeça de lista pegando o campo próximo do penúltimo elemento da lista.